# Unable to remove huge spaces between results

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, data-cleaning

I've written a script in python to scrape some text out of some html elements. The script I've written can parse it. However, the problem is the data are getting parsed with a huge spaces between them. I tried with `.strip()` method but it didn't have any effect on the result. How can I fix it?

The html elements:

```
html="""
<div class="organisation-details">

    <div class="personnel shaded">
                        <h3>KEY PERSONNEL</h3>
                        <p>
                                Director: Andrew Bickerton<br>
                                Director: Andrew Connor<br>
                                Office Manager: Tom Marchant<br>
                        </p>
                    </div>

    <div class="company-type shaded">
                        <h3>COMPANY TYPE</h3>
                        <p>
                                                        Importer
                        </p>
                    </div>

    <div class="company-details shaded">
                        <h3>COMPANY DETAILS</h3>
                        <p>
                                Year Established: 1984 <br>
                                                        VAT No: GB 413 3611 93<br>
                                                        No of Employees: 1-20<br>
                        </p>
                    </div>


</div>
"""
```

This script:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring

tree = fromstring(html)
for title in tree.cssselect(".organisation-details"):
    key = title.cssselect("h3:contains('KEY PERSONNEL')+p")[0].text_content().strip()
    details = title.cssselect("h3:contains('COMPANY DETAILS')+p")[0].text_content().strip()
    ctype = title.cssselect("h3:contains('COMPANY TYPE')+p")[0].text_content().strip()
    print(key,details,ctype)
```

The output I'm having:

```
Director: Andrew Bickerton
                                Director: Andrew Connor
                                Office Manager: Tom Marchant Year Established: 1984 
                                                        VAT No: GB 413 3611 93
                                                        No of Employees: 1-20 Importer
```

The result I'm after (or anything closer):

```
Director: Andrew Bickerton
Director: Andrew Connor
Office Manager: Tom Marchant 
Year Established: 1984 
VAT No: GB 413 3611 93
No of Employees: 1-20
Importer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `key`, `details` and `ctype` contain multiple lines and whitespace in the middle of the strings.  You need to split those on newline and strip each item.  Something like:

```
for piece in key.split('\n'):
    print(piece.strip())
```

and repeat for `details` and `ctype`.

Answer (score 0):

When a browser presents that html to you, it pays no attention to external white space at the beginning and end of strings. Python (or any other programming language) takes white space in strings literally. Coincidentally, I was stumped myself over a similar situation just yesterday.